# Connect to a database other than the default database in redshift

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework, amazon-redshift

I need to connect my django app to a database that is other than the default database in redshift. When I connect it to default database , the connection is successfull. when I connect it to a database that is not the default it gives an error message saying

> "django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "test" does not exist

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
      'NAME': 'test',
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
      'USER': 'test',
      'PASSWORD': '######',
      'HOST': '############.redshift.amazonaws.com',
      'PORT': ####
  }
}
```

Comment: I use psycopg2 to connect to Redshift and it works fine, so there's no reason as to why this shouldn't work, assuming the database exists on that cluster. 
Try connecting to the same database using a SQL client like SQL Workbench and see if you face the same issue.

Comment: @Dilani - Did you resolve this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL you connect to a database, not a schema. In your settings.py `NAME` should be the name of the database you want to connect to. The default database for PostgreSQL is `postgres`.

`USER` is the actual PostgreSQL user you want to log in as. Again the default is  `postgres`.

They are two separate things. You can be logged in to PostgreSQL as the user `postgres` and connected to the database `test`.

Comment: I have edited the question. That was a mistake. In the above scenario name of the database that I want to connect to is 'test' . In redshift I have configured the default database with the name 'default_one'. When I connect my django app to 'default_one', it is successful. when I connect to  ' test' it raises an error.

Comment: Does the test database exist? and if so does the USER you are logging in as have access to it?

Comment: yes, the database exists and the user has access to it as well.